# Creating Dataframe with JSON Keys

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a JSON file which resulted from YouTube's iframe API and I want to put this JSON data into a pandas dataframe, where each JSON key will be a column, and each record should be a new row.

Normally I would use a loop and iterate over the rows of the JSON but this particular JSON looks like this :

```
[  
   "{\"timemillis\":1563467467703,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:07,703\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:02\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.3,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}",
   "{\"timemillis\":1563467468705,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:08,705\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:03\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.5,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}"

]
```

In this JSON not every key is written as a new line. How can I extract the keys in this case, and express them as columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Pythonic Solution would be to use the **keys and values API** of the Python Dictionary.

it should be something like this:

```
ls = [
   "{\"timemillis\":1563467467703,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:07,703\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:02\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.3,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}",
   "{\"timemillis\":1563467468705,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:08,705\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:03\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.5,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}"

]
ls = [json.loads(j) for j in ls]

keys = [j.keys() for j in ls] # this will get you all the keys
vals = [j.values() for j in ls] # this will get the values and then you can do something with it 

print(keys)
print(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

easiest way is to leverage `json_normalize` from `pandas`.

```
import json
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize

input_dict = [
   "{\"timemillis\":1563467467703,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:07,703\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:02\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.3,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}",
   "{\"timemillis\":1563467468705,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:08,705\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:03\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.5,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}"

]
input_json = [json.loads(j) for j in input_dict]

df = json_normalize(input_json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking to break down your key and values and want keys as a column,and values as a row:
This is my approach and plz always provide how your expected output should like

ChainMap flats your dict in key and values and pretty much is self explanatory.

```
data = ["{\"timemillis\":1563467467703,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:07,703\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:02\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.3,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}","{\"timemillis\":1563467468705,\"date\":\"18.7.2019\",\"time\":\"18:31:08,705\",\"videoId\":\"0HJx2JhQKQk\",\"startSecond\":\"0\",\"stopSecond\":\"90\",\"playerStateNumeric\":1,\"playerStateVerbose\":\"Playing\",\"curTimeFormatted\":\"0:03\",\"totalTimeFormatted\":\"9:46\",\"playoutLevelPercent\":0.5,\"bufferLevelPercent\":1.4,\"qual\":\"large\",\"qualLevels\":[\"hd720\",\"large\",\"medium\",\"small\",\"tiny\",\"auto\"],\"playbackRate\":1,\"playbackRates\":[0.25,0.5,0.75,1,1.25,1.5,1.75,2],\"playerErrorNumeric\":\"\",\"playerErrorVerbose\":\"\"}"]

import json
from collections import ChainMap

data = [json.loads(i) for i in data]
data = dict(ChainMap(*data))

keys = []
vals = []

for k,v in data.items():
    keys.append(k)
    vals.append(v)

data = pd.DataFrame(zip(keys,vals)).T
new_header = data.iloc[0]
data = data[1:]
data.columns = new_header


#startSecond    playbackRates   playbackRate    qual    totalTimeFormatted  timemillis  playerStateNumeric  playerStateVerbose  playerErrorNumeric  date    time    stopSecond  bufferLevelPercent  playerErrorVerbose  qualLevels  videoId curTimeFormatted    playoutLevelPercent
  #0             [0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 1.75, 2]   1   large   9:46    1563467467703   1   Playing     18.7.2019   18:31:07,703    90  1.4     [hd720, large, medium, small, tiny, auto]   0HJx2JhQKQk 0:02    0.3
```