# how to parse a json column in a df where we append new column using selected keys

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, data-wrangling

Hi I am beginner in python & R. I had a quick question:

```py
#I have a data frame that looks like this:

# Import pandas library
import pandas as pd

# initialize list of lists
data = [['BarackObama', {'cap': {'english': 0.014543680863094452, 'universal': 0.005213309669283597}, 
                         'categories': {'content': 0.13252377443365895, 'friend': 0.27037007428252813, 
                                        'network': 0.07904647486470226, 'sentiment': 0.13142975907620189, 
                                        'temporal': 0.0560116435619808, 'user': 0.2120791504162319}, 
                         'display_scores': {'content': 0.7, 'english': 1.1, 'friend': 1.4, 'network': 0.4, 
                                            'sentiment': 0.7, 'temporal': 0.3, 'universal': 0.6, 'user': 1.1}, 
                         'scores': {'english': 0.22180647190550215, 'universal': 0.11116719108518804}, 
                         'user': {'id_str': '813286', 'screen_name': 'BarackObama'}}],
        ['realDonaldTrump', {'cap': {'english': 0.0014187924969112314, 'universal': 0.0018655051726169808}, 
                             'categories': {'content': 0.062020196630026815, 'friend': 0.19869669732913162, 
                                            'network': 0.05312993020038088, 'sentiment': 0.05985886859558471, 
                                            'temporal': 0.07924665710801207, 'user': 0.037517839108884524}, 
                             'display_scores': {'content': 0.3, 'english': 0.2, 'friend': 1.0, 'network': 0.3, 
                                                'sentiment': 0.3, 'temporal': 0.4, 'universal': 0.2, 'user': 0.2},
                             'scores': {'english': 0.03265990956683609, 'universal': 0.032398754737074244}, 
                             'user': {'id_str': '25073877', 'screen_name': 'realDonaldTrump'}}]]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'botScore'])

# print dataframe.
print(df)

#              Name                                           botScore
#0      BarackObama  {'cap': {'english': 0.014543680863094452, 'uni...
#1  realDonaldTrump  {'cap': {'english': 0.0014187924969112314, 'un...
```

so how can I have something like this where I choose the keys & values from `display_score` portion of the json in dataframe and append them to existing data frame?

```py
# data-wrangling part using the display_scores key in json column....

# print(df)

#              Name   botScore     english   friend   sentiment
#0      BarackObama   {'cap':...     1.1      1.4      0.7
#1  realDonaldTrump   {'cap':...     0.3      1.0      0.3
```

I would really appreciate your help in this! I looked at several past posts but I couldn't solve my problem using their approach:
[Creating Dataframe with JSON Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57220889/creating-dataframe-with-json-keys)
[How to insert specific keys from json file into a data frame in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58358444/how-to-insert-specific-keys-from-json-file-into-a-data-frame-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First, fix the `data`

- Add the name at position `0` within each list to the `dict` at position `1`
- Convert the `list of lists` to a `list of dicts`

```py
for x in data:
    x[1]['name'] = x[0]

data2 = [x[1] for x in data]
```

### Process the list of dicts

- Use the [flatten package](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)

  - I'm going to just include the specific function here

```py
def flatten_json(nested_json: dict, exclude: list=[''], sep='_') -> dict:
    """
    Flatten a list of nested dicts.
    """
    out = dict()
    def flatten(x: (list, dict, str), name: str='', exclude=exclude):
        if type(x) is dict:
            for a in x:
                if a not in exclude:
                    flatten(x[a], f'{name}{a}{sep}')
        elif type(x) is list:
            i = 0
            for a in x:
                flatten(a, f'{name}{i}{sep}')
                i += 1
        else:
            out[name[:-1]] = x

    flatten(nested_json)
    return out

df = pd.DataFrame([flatten_json(x) for x in data2])

print(df)

   cap_english  cap_universal  categories_content  categories_friend  categories_network  categories_sentiment  categories_temporal  categories_user  display_scores_content  display_scores_english  display_scores_friend  display_scores_network  display_scores_sentiment  display_scores_temporal  display_scores_universal  display_scores_user  scores_english  scores_universal user_id_str user_screen_name             name
0     0.014544       0.005213            0.132524           0.270370            0.079046              0.131430             0.056012         0.212079                     0.7                     1.1                    1.4                     0.4                       0.7                      0.3                       0.6                  1.1        0.221806          0.111167      813286      BarackObama      BarackObama
1     0.001419       0.001866            0.062020           0.198697            0.053130              0.059859             0.079247         0.037518                     0.3                     0.2                    1.0                     0.3                       0.3                      0.4                       0.2                  0.2        0.032660          0.032399    25073877  realDonaldTrump  realDonaldTrump
```

#### Other resources:

- [Thinking Recursively in Python](https://realpython.com/python-thinking-recursively/)
- [Flattening JSON objects in Python](https://towardsdatascience.com/flattening-json-objects-in-python-f5343c794b10)
- [flatten package](https://github.com/amirziai/flatten)
- [How to flatten nested JSON recursively, with flatten_json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58442723/how-to-flatten-nested-json-recursively-with-flatten-json)

Comment: Thank you Mr. Trenton for a detailed answer, I appreciate it sir!

Answer (score 1):

You can use python's [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to collate all the entries 'display_scores' in the botScore column and concat back to the main dataframe:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
#iterate through the display_scores key 
#and append to dictionary
for ent in df.botScore:
    for k, v in ent['display_scores'].items():
        d[k].append(v)
d

defaultdict(list,
            {'content': [0.7, 0.3],
             'english': [1.1, 0.2],
             'friend': [1.4, 1.0],
             'network': [0.4, 0.3],
             'sentiment': [0.7, 0.3],
             'temporal': [0.3, 0.4],
             'universal': [0.6, 0.2],
             'user': [1.1, 0.2]})

#combine main dataframe with the dictionary
pd.concat([df,pd.DataFrame(d)],axis=1)
    Name            botScore    content english friend  network sentiment   temporal    universal   user
0   BarackObama {'cap': {'english': 0.014543680863094452, 'uni...   0.7 1.1 1.4 0.4 0.7 0.3 0.6 1.1
1   realDonaldTrump {'cap': {'english': 0.0014187924969112314, 'un...   0.3 0.2 1.0 0.3 0.3 0.4 0.2 0.2
```

Comment: Thank you sammywemmy for another beautiful answer! Take care buddy :)